# How to root Alcatel OT-997D?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting

I currently have an Alcatel OT-997D which has the MTK6577 chipset and runs ICS 4.04. I've looked mostly through threads at xda-devs and I've tried various root methods including: ["root many android"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) - I get "mount access denied", "ICS/JB Universal root" - When trying to update in stock recovery the file fails verification, "MTK Droid root" - Reboots phone and backup/restore prompts appear but no results.

Does anyone know any other "universal" rooting methods or ones specific to my device?

Comment: I've just linked to your question from our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/16575) (as our policy is: one rooting question per device, yours now is marked for this device :) Though I have no specific answer, you might want to follow that link: at the end of the devices list follows a list of known rooting methods. Maybe you have more look with one of the others. Crossing fingers!

Comment: Thanks Izzy! There's a few I haven't tried yet so I'll take a look...

Comment: This is somewhat late, but for anyone else looking to root their MTK based devices, Framaroot is excellent in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Before you begin, I enabled developer mode and I'm not sure if it makes a difference but this is what worked for me so you might as well:

Open **settings**, click on **About phone**, scroll down to **Build number** and tap **Build number** *seven times*.

I tried many different methods on a similar alcatel phone with a mtk6582 and I also got error messages from various exploit methods.

However, here are two methods that were successful.

[iroot](http://www.iroot.com/)

Root is successful and uses a *one click* method. However, in order to gain file access, you must install "root file explorer" and which is a paid app. For me, paying for an app is not an option.

[kingroot](https://king-root.net/)

Download and install kingroot. This one also uses a *one click*
 method and obtaining root is successful. This is the method I recommend as kingroot will allow you to allocate root permission to individual applications.

After installation and successful root, click the gear icon on the upper right hand corner of the main screen. If you need to, close the app and open it again to view the main screen.

Enable the option **Enable Root authorization**.

Then, under **Root authorization setting**, enable the first three options, **Smart authorization**, **Backup Root permission,** and **Keep the Root upgraded.**

For me, I set **Authorization count down** to 10 seconds and **Default timeout** to **Allow** just to get things working. Exit KingRoot.

Next, install [ES file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) and then open KingRoot. Go to **Root Authorization** and select **Allow** for ES File Explorer.

Open ES File Explorer and click the menu icon on the upper left hand corner of the screen. Scroll down and expand the Tools section of this menu and toggle the option ON for **Root Explorer**. Swipe the menu left to close the menu and a few more times to get to the files where you will have full root access to modify these files.

Additionally, KingRoot has the ability to Uninstall default apps and there is also Kingmaster which allows you to manage and restrict apps to obtain full performance of your device.

However, Kingmaster is in Chinese. Most of the app restriction is obvious as red restricts the app and green allows.